# How to get the data of special fileds from all xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have this kind of data in my Xml response coming from server it starts and end with the "NewDataSet"tag , and under this tag there are several "Table" tag. and in this table tag I want to get the value of some fields let say CallDate, CallDuration,from all Table tag. so that I can show data correspondingly. But In all tutorial on net they are showing the data as it is after parsing. So My problem is how to get the data from those special fields from all table tag in this Xml .I ma sure I am quite clear in my question . Please help me

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<CallDetailId>06012015192014733680011</CallDetailId>
<CallID>83A26D3811000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 19:20:14</CallDate>
<CalledBy>337</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>368</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>true</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>368</ExtensionValue>
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>true</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>060120151424080020030003</CallDetailId>
<CallID>1F5D6D3803000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>5</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 14:24:08</CallDate>
<CalledBy>2003</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>210</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRECORDAudio\Repository\from\150106\0207\202_06012015 142408003_0003_2003.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>O</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>2003</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
```

I am doing this

```
    result = xmlStringComingFromServer
    Document dom = null;
                    DocumentBuilder builder;
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
                    try {
                        InputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(results.getBytes("utf-8"));
                        factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        dom = builder.parse(resultStream);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (dom != null) {
                        Log.v("Dom is Not Null", dom.toString() + "");
                        NodeList nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet");



                        /*




                        putting new data here
                         */

                        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


//                        NodeList nl = dom.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

                        // looping through all item nodes <item>
                        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                            // creating new HashMap
                            Log.v("For Rounds",i+"");
                            Element e = (Element)nodeList.item(i);

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put("Table",e.getElementsByTagName("Table").item(i).getTextContent());
                            //map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
//                            map.put("CallDuration",e.getElementsByTagName("CallDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
//                            map.put("CalledBy",e.getElementsByTagName("CalledBy").item(0).getTextContent());
//                            map.put("CalledTo",e.getElementsByTagName("CalledTo").item(0).getTextContent());
//                            map.put("FirstName",e.getElementsByTagName("FirstName").item(0).getTextContent());
//                            map.put("LastName",e.getElementsByTagName("LastName").item(0).getTextContent());

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            menuItems.add(map);
                    }
```

Comment: Any code relating to parsing? What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Tag name with values after converting xml string by Document builder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943562/how-to-get-the-tag-name-with-values-after-converting-xml-string-by-document-buil)

Comment: showed What I a doing @shkschneider

Comment: @paulkayuk yes I have asked that question But nothing is really helping me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XmlPullParser to parse xml faster and more memory efficient than loading a Dom.

```
 try {
      XmlPullParser xpp;
      XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(mInput, "UTF-8");

        String N = "";  //I know it's capitalized but that's how I do temp strings.

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (true) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                // code taken from AsyncTask check cancel each loop your code 
                // may not need this check
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return RESULT_ABORTED;  
                }
                N = xpp.getName();
                if (N.equals("CallDate")) {
                    String callDate = xpp.getText();
                } else if (N.equals("somethingelse")) {
                    String somethingelse = xpp.getText();
                }
            } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                break;
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        ret = RESULT_ERROR;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ret = RESULT_ERROR;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Is this will take all the Call date from each Table Tag? ?

Comment: @Black first read the code and try to understand it, then add it to your own solution, and if you still have any doubts about what it is doing, use breakpoints to step through the code and examine the variables as you go.

Comment: yeah , I was planning to do this , I tried to understand the code and some how I am close to it . and thank you @paulkayuk for throughout your support . You are great

Comment: @paulkayuk I have another problem regarding to this app but this is relevant should I ask it here in comment ?

Comment: after doing this so I got the data into following form
Response XML:
    <CallsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><SearchCallsResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
    &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;AgentHangup&gt;true&lt;/AgentHangup&gt;
    &lt;CallDetailId&gt;140120151439395690100016&lt;/CallDetailId&gt;
    
    &lt;CallDuration&gt;9&lt;/CallDuration&gt;
    &lt;EncryptedCall&gt;false&lt;/EncryptedCall&gt;

Comment: this is just sample from the form of data that I have gotten after applying this method @danny